# How can I change column widths in bootstrap when I only have access to CSS (no way for me to change the HTML)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7">column md-7</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-1">spacer md-1</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">column md-4</div>
```

I've volunteered to do some work on a page for a conference about accessibility. The organisers have used a "drag and drop" page builder but it has no editing ability for sub pages. The page they need to change has a small amount of content in the md-7 column but most of the text of the speaker bios is in the md-4 column and looks much too narrow.
They have asked me to use the "Add custom CSS functionality" to adjust the width of the columns.

[image]

So my question is how to use ONLY CSS to increase the width of the third column. 
I have tried the following:

```
.col-12.col-md-7 { max-width:30%; }
.col-12.col-md-4 { flex-grow:5 !important; }
.col-12.col-md-4 { max-width:70% !important; }
```

and it expands the third column nicely on a regular screen but falls apart on mobile as the 30% width is too small for the first column.

Comment: Did you look at the styling Bootstrap applies to those classes for each breakpoint? It would be a matter of copying all that and modifying it.

Comment: You could use css ```@media``` for mobile compatibility

Comment: Yes, I thought I wouldn't be able to add a media query via the custom CSS input box but it does seem possible so I'll follow up on that. Thanks @FourCinnamon0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..and it expands the third column nicely on a regular screen but falls
>   apart on mobile as the 30% width is too small for the first column.

Perhaps I misunderstand the problem, but can you not just use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)? BS4 use among other media queries these definitions (your CSS included) :

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-12.col-md-7 { max-width:30%; }
  .col-12.col-md-4 { flex-grow:5 !important; }
  .col-12.col-md-4 { max-width:70% !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-12.col-md-7 { max-width: 60%; } /* perhaps 60% fits better */
  .col-12.col-md-4 { flex-grow:5 !important; } /* change other classes accordingly */
  .col-12.col-md-4 { max-width:70% !important; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had assumed that I couldn't do media queries via the custom CSS input but now I've tried them they seem to work fine so that's the way to go.

Comment: Why not use just the media query that applies to the `md-*` classes? `@media (min-width: 768px) { styles }`? Since `col-12` is already 100% width, you can just target for the actual breakpoint BS4 uses.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use inline css, you can define a class for all columns separately. You can then select and replace any column with css. This method is a bit laborious. If you want it to change in mobile view, you have to use @media
so you have to use this method and arrange each one individually in whatever size you want it to look like.

Html:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7 my-col1">column md-7</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-1 my-col2">spacer md-1</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 my-col3">column md-4</div>
```

Css:

```
.my-col3 {
   // what if you want to
 }
```

If you want to solve the size problem using only bootstrap other than css, you need to look at the column properties in more detail. You can specify how much space to take up in what size, so you don't have to add css properties. When you do this, you can also adjust the mobile and tablet appearance by taking advantage of the bootstrap responsive features.
in short, it would be a more logical move to adjust the responsive according to the column dimensions.

Comment: Yes, if I could add a class then I could style that class with CSS but in this case I only have access to the CSS of the page via the "Add custom CSS" input box in the event dashboard. So without direct access to the HTML I don't think there is a way for me to add a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole thing inside a `container-fluid` and then define a new class for every column. Then change the width of the column in css and use `@media` query to define the transformation in media breakpoints.

Comment: _(no way for me to change the HTML)?_ It's in the title they can't change the HTML.